# Trouble using the Moment module

Tags: parse-platform

Here is some Parse cloud code I am having problem with:

```
var moment = require('moment');

Parse.Cloud.define
("myCloudFunction", function(request, response)
 {
    var now = moment();
    var later = moment("2017-07-09T20:00:00");
    var x = 7;
    if (later.isAfter(now)) x = x-1;
    else x = x+1;
    console.log(x);
 });
```

I get this error message when I run it:

```
Error: TypeError: Object Sun Jul 09 2017 20:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC) has no method 'isAfter' at main.js:406:12 (Code: 141, Version: 1.2.18)
```

Of course I have simplified things to come to the point of my question.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hosted version of moment.js file used by Cloud Code is stuck at version 1.7.2 and the `isAfter` method is 2.0+.

Download a new copy of moment.js and put it in your cloud/ folder, then require it like this:

```
var moment = require('cloud/moment.js');
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `var moment = require('moment');` needs to be outside the function as it defines a requirement for the whole file. I usually put all my `require` statements up the top of the file.

So your above code should look like this:

```
var moment = require('moment');

Parse.Cloud.define
("myCloudFunction", function(request, response)
 {
    var now = moment();
    var later = moment("2017-07-09T20:00:00");
    var x = 7;
    if (later.isAfter(now)) x = x-1;
    else x = x+1;
    console.log(x);
 });
```

Comment: Putting the line (var moment = require('moment');) outside the function (top of the file or not), does not make any difference. I still see the exact same error message.

Comment: I suggest keeping a require inside of a function, if and only if it is limited to that function.  Reason being, it will be fetched/loaded/parsed during deploys and other function calls.

Comment: @Fosco can you shed any light on why the `isAfter()` call on a `moment` is not working? I'm wondering if it is linked to the version of the JS SDK perhaps?

Comment: The version of moment js we host on Parse is stuck at version 1.7.2.  Those methods are 2.0+

Comment: @Fosco it would be well worth mentioning this in the docs since the API link given show what version methods are in

Comment: @TimothyWalters Good point... I've just submitted this change for review.

Comment: @TimothyWalters it will be there after our next deploy.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that some of the functions are no working even in the native moment.js supported by parse (moment v1.7.2)... while using add function it doesn't work... only when working with my downloaded version of moment (2.8.4)

See for yourselves with below code:

```
var moment = require('moment');
var moment2 = require('cloud/moment.js');

Parse.Cloud.define ("momentChecks", function(request, response)
{
    var later =   moment("2017-07-09T20:00:00");
    var later2 =  moment("2017-07-09T20:00:00");
    var later3 = moment2("2017-07-09T20:00:00");

     later.add(1, 'days').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    later2.add(2, 'days').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");
    later3.add(2, 'days').format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a");

    var message = "\nlater: " + later.format() + "\nlater2: " + later2.format() + "\nlater3: " + later3.format();
    console.log(message);
    response.success(message);
});
```

Comment: I'd opened a bug case [link](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/865098890178583) and answer is that it appears that in moment.js 1.7.2 the order was different.  Now it should be: later2.add('days', 2)